# App Engine Pull Queue tasks disappear before being properly handled

Tags: java, google-app-engine

**Update 4 - rephrasing question for clarity**

I am using Pull Queues to feed back-end workers tasks that send push notifications. I can see the front-end instance queue the task in the logs. However, the task is only occasionally handled by the back-end. I see no indication of why the task disappears prior to being handled and deleted from the queue.

This may be related: I am seeing an unusually high number of [TransientFailureException](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/TransientFailureException)s when attempting to lease tasks from the queue - despite sleeping between attempts.

Everything works properly on my development server (and an earlier version had worked in production) but production is no longer working properly. At first I thought it was a certificate issue. However, notifications are sometimes sent when the backend first starts.

There is no indication that an error is happening except for the [TransientFailureException](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/TransientFailureException) when I call leaseTasks on the queue. Also, it seems to take a very long time for my logs to show up.

I can provide more information and code snippets as needed.

Thanks for the help.

**Update 1:**

The application uses 10 pull queues. It would normally use 2 but queue tagging is still considered experimental. They are declared in the standard fashion:

```
<queue>
    <name>gcm-henchdist</name>
    <mode>pull</mode>
</queue>
```

The lease tasks function is:

```
public boolean processBatchOfTasks()
{
    List< TaskHandle > tasks = attemptLeaseTasks();

    if( null == tasks || tasks.isEmpty() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    processLeasedTasks( tasks );
    return true;
}

private List< TaskHandle > attemptLeaseTasks()
{
    for( int attemptNnum = 1; !LifecycleManager.getInstance().isShuttingDown(); ++attemptNnum )
    {
        try
        {
            return m_taskQueue.leaseTasks( m_numLeaseTimeUnits, m_leaseTimeUnit, m_maxTasksPerLease );
        } catch( TransientFailureException exc )
        {
            LOG.warn( "TransientFailureException when leasing tasks from queue '{}'", m_taskQueue.getQueueName(), exc );
            ApiProxy.flushLogs();
        } catch( ApiDeadlineExceededException exc )
        {
            LOG.warn( "ApiDeadlineExceededException when when leasing tasks from queue '{}'",
                    m_taskQueue.getQueueName(), exc );
            ApiProxy.flushLogs();
        }

        if( !backOff( attemptNnum ) )
        {
            LOG.warn( "Failed to lease tasks." );
            break;
        }
    }

    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

where the lease variables are 30, TimeUnit.MINUTES, 100 respectively

the processBatchOfTasks function is polled via:

```
private void startPollingForClient( EClientType clientType )
{
    InterimApnsCertificateConfig config = InterimApnsCertificateConfigMgr.getConfig( clientType );
    Queue notificationQueue = QueueFactory.getQueue( config.getQueueId().getName() );

    ApplePushNotificationWorker worker = new ApplePushNotificationWorker(
            notificationQueue,
            m_messageConverter.getObjectMapper(),
            config.getCertificateBytes(),
            config.getPassword(),
            config.isProduction() );

    LOG.info( "Started worker for {} polling queue {}", clientType, notificationQueue.getQueueName() );

    while ( !LifecycleManager.getInstance().isShuttingDown() )
    {
        boolean tasksProcessed = worker.processBatchOfTasks();
        ApiProxy.flushLogs();

        if ( !tasksProcessed )
        {
            // Wait before trying to lease tasks again.
            try
            {
                //LOG.info( "Going to sleep" );
                Thread.sleep( MILLISECONDS_TO_WAIT_WHEN_NO_TASKS_LEASED );
                //LOG.info( "Waking up" );
            } catch ( InterruptedException exc )
            {
                LOG.info( "Polling loop interrupted. Terminating loop.", exc );
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    LOG.info( "Instance is shutting down" );
}
```

and the thread is created via:

```
Thread thread = ThreadManager.createBackgroundThread( new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        startPollingForClient( clientType );
    }
} );

thread.start();
```

GCM notifications are handled in a similar fashion.

**Update 2**

The following is the backoff function. I have verified in the logs (with both GAE and my own timestamps) that the sleep is incrementing properly

```
private boolean backOff( int attemptNo )
{
    // Exponential back off between 2 seconds and 64 seconds with jitter
    // 0..1000 ms.
    attemptNo = Math.min( 6, attemptNo );
    int backOffTimeInSeconds = 1 << attemptNo;
    long backOffTimeInMilliseconds = backOffTimeInSeconds * 1000 + (int)( Math.random() * 1000 );

    LOG.info( "Backing off for {} milliseconds from queue '{}'", backOffTimeInMilliseconds, m_taskQueue.getQueueName() );
    ApiProxy.flushLogs();

    try
    {
        Thread.sleep( backOffTimeInMilliseconds );

    } catch( InterruptedException e )
    {
        return false;
    }

    LOG.info( "Waking up from {} milliseconds sleep for queue '{}'", backOffTimeInMilliseconds, m_taskQueue.getQueueName() );
    ApiProxy.flushLogs();

    return true;
}
```

**Update 3**

The tasks are added to the queue within a transaction on a front-end instance:

```
if( null != queueType )
{
    String deviceName;
    int numDevices = deviceList.size();
    for ( int iDevice = 0; iDevice < numDevices; ++iDevice )
    {
        deviceName = deviceList.get( iDevice ).getName();
        LOG.info( "Queueing Your-Turn notification for user: {} device: {} queue: {}", user.getId(), deviceName, queueType.getName() );
        Queue queue = QueueFactory.getQueue( queueType.getName() );

        queue.addAsync( TaskOptions.Builder.withMethod( TaskOptions.Method.PULL )
                .param( "alertLocKey", "NOTIF_YOUR_TURN" ).param( "device", deviceName ) );
    }
}
```

I know that the transaction succeeds because the database updates correctly.

In the logs I see the "Queuing Your-Turn notification..." entry, but I see nothing appear on the back-end logs.

In the administration panel, I see Task Queue API Calls increment by 1 as well as Task Queue Stored Task Count increment by 1. However, the queue that was written to shows zero in both the Tasks In Queue and Leased In Last Minute fields.

Comment: Yes please do provide more information.

Comment: @MartinBerends Updated! If there is anything specific that you would like to see, please let me know.

Comment: @MartinBerends I have changed the name of my leaseTasks functions to attemptLeaseTasks so that it is easier to comment on the code as you suggested. Also, I have placed additional spacing between the catch statement and the backoff call so that it doesn't blend in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the culprit may have been that I was calling addAsync when enqueuing the task instead of just calling add.

I replaced the call and things seem to be consistently working now. I would like to know why this makes a difference and will update the answer when I find the reason.

Comment: Using addAsync should make no difference because it affects only flow control around the enqueue operation.  Perhaps the transient failure exceptions thrown by m_taskQueue.leaseTasks() are much less transient now.  The logs might tell.

Comment: @MartinBerends That's what I thought too. However, the exceptions are as prevalent as ever. Given the nature of the error, I had a feeling that an innocuous change would solve the problem. I wish I had a Google engineer who could explain why.

Comment: Are the exceptions still prevalent when using addAsync as well?

Comment: @MartinBerends Yes, they are appear frequently with both add and addAsync. I believe that the error lies not with the retrieval and processing of the tasks but with the enqueueing. It makes sense when we consider Update 3 (above). The "Tasks In Queue" fields and "Leased in Last Minute" fields remain at zero despite the API call numbers incrementing. This would also explain the lack of logs related to the processing and the tasks not being found (even though they were never deleted). So it may be the case that they weren't disappearing, they were just never being properly created.

Comment: Ouch.  Then the linked example you based your code on might give the same problem under heavy use.  I recently gained the use of an iPhone for testing, so when I get a round tuit, I'll attempt to deploy that original project.  Round tuits are rare, so no promises about when, but this problem has turned into something of a challenge.  For you I guess it has turned into more of an annoyance.  If the original code loses tasks it deserves to be reported as a platform bug.

Comment: @MartinBerends I believe that, in the linked example, they use add in stead of addAsync. I may have changed it to addAsync with the assumption that it would allow my transaction to return more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The [TransientFailureException JavaDoc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/TransientFailureException) says that "The requested operation may succeed if attempted again" (because the failure is transient).  Therefore when this exception is thrown your code should loop back and repeat the leaseTasks call.  Furthermore AppEngine does not have to redo the request itself because it notified you via the exception that you should do so.

It's a pity you repeat the method name leaseTasks as one of your own because now it's not clear which one I'm referring to when I mention leaseTasks.  Still, wrap the inner call to m_taskQueue.leaseTasks in a while loop and an additional try block to catch only the TransientFailureException.  Use a flag to end the while loop only if that exception is not thrown.

Is that enough explanation, or do you need a complete source code listing?

Comment: That's what the backoff function does and I have verified in the logs that it sleeps for the prescribed amount of time and then tries again. The failure happens frequently even when waiting several seconds between attempts.

This follows the example created by Google at: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-ios-push-notification-sample-backend-java

Comment: I pressed enter to make a space but that submitted the comment: The frustrating thing is that the code was working properly in production but when I scaled it up and added more queues, it ceased to function. It is especially frustrating since it functions properly on the dev server.

Comment: I should also comment that my logs never show the task being deleted. So, once its lease expires, it should return to the queue where it is attempted again. However, the tasks seem to be disappearing without being deleted.

Comment: The above three comments amount to a rejection of my suggestion.  You have not considered it or show no willingness to try it.  The backoff logic as it stands is flawed.  After it executes, the outer for loop proceeds to the next task in the queue and previous transient failed task is forgotten!  Please add an inner while loop and an inner catch if you want me to continue to try to help you.

Comment: The logic in [CloudPushSample for iOS - Java Backend](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-ios-push-notification-sample-backend-java/blob/master/src/com/google/cloud/solutions/mobilepushnotification/PushNotificationWorker.java) is flawed with the same bug.

Comment: Oh, I'm not dismissing your suggestion at all. I was under the impression that the code was already doing exactly what you suggested. m_taskQueue.leaseTasks fails to lease any tasks, the exception is caught, backoff sleeps the thread and then m_taskQueue.leaseTasks is called again. The For loop only increments a counter that increases the sleep duration if another exception occurs. The conditional for backoff is only called if a InterruptedException is caught during the sleep. I'm still a bit of a Java newbie and would love to try your suggestion if you can show me an example.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that, I now agree with you and feel I was too hasty in my initial diagnosis.  I apologise for my arrogance and am considering deleting this answer.

Comment: No worries, Martin. I'm just glad that you're here trying to help :)